# How to pad 0 to align the file name middle in the file name with PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I have such files in the current directory:

[image]

But I want to rename the file to

[image]

How to use `PowerShell` to implement it?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your files are actually named "image*.png":

```
$files = "C:\files"

# for each file
gci $files | % { 
    $n = "0000" + $_.BaseName -replace "image",""     # pad the number with "0000". eg 0000999
    $n = $n.SubString($n.Length - 4, 4)               # get the 4 right-most numbers. eg 0999
    $name = "image" + $n + $_.Extension               # prepare the new name

    rename-item $files\$_ $files\$name -WhatIf
}
```

Remove `-WhatIf` after testing.

This question looks like a continuation of your last. It would be better to tune your original question with requirements rather than posting a second question.

Comment: I have posted a new method in following after inspire by you. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I will drop the `image` from the file name

```
ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'image',''}
```

Then I pad a `0` into the file name

```
ls | %{Rename-Item $_.Name $_.Name.PadLeft(8,'0')}
```

Last I will add the prefix back into the file name

```
ls | %{Rename-Item $_.Name ('image'+$_.Name)}
```